# Getting Time as 00:00:00.0

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

below is my stored procedure

```
create procedure sp_process_job(@request_id varchar(25), @host varchar(20),
     created_on varchar(25)
) 
as
begin

    set dateformat mdy
    SELECT CAST(@created_on as datetime)
    insert into t_job_details(request_id ,host, created_on) 
    values(@request_id,@host,@created_on)

end
```

When I cast date using `SELECT CAST(@created_on as datetime)`

I get output as `2012-06-22 00:00:00.0` Time is `00:00:00.0`

I want it as `12:45:06.0`. Why I get 0 in all places?

Edit:
Calling the above procedure from java code

```
Date date = new Date();
Date insert_date = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
String insertquery = "{ call sp_process_job (?,?,?) }";

cs = con.prepareCall(insertquery.toString());
            cs.setString(1, id);
            cs.setString(2, host);
            cs.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) insert_date);
cs.execute();

            con.commit();
```

Comment: what is the value of `@created_on`? what parameters are you calling to this function?

Comment: How are you calling this stored procedure? Why are you passing a datetime value as a string? Why are you using `set dateformat` rather than specifying a format using `CONVERT`? Is it really your intent to just return the converted datetime value, but then use the string value in the `insert` and rely on an implicit conversion?

Comment: It doesn't look like your passing any time information *to* the stored procedure. [java.sql.DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html): "To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero..."

Comment: Also, BTW, avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedure names. That prefix is "reserved" by Microsoft for system stored procedure names.

Comment: thanks alot @ Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Change this `SELECT CAST(@created_on as datetime)` To `SELECT CAST(@created_on +' 12:45:06.0' as datetime)` works?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `java.sql.Timestamp` in the Java code instead of java.sql.date which saves only date not time.  And also `cs.setTimestamp`

```
    java.sql.Timestamp insert_date = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
    ....
    cs.setTimestamp(3, insert_date);
```